# How to display total sum values in summary band of groups partial sums

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report like the image below:

[image]

Note that the sections separated by a blank space are grouped by the month and are iterated over a group band. I want to put partial in the summary band by the type of the register, like in the example figure get the sum for Register type A in January = 10, February = 5, March = 1 so as the total = 10 + 5 + 1 = 16. So the summary will look like:

[image]

How can I achieve that kind of conditional sum in jasper? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a little bit with iReport I found a solution: to get the partial sum by type you have to add a variable that has the calculation type as "sum" and the reset type set as "Report". Once you set the values you have to create a variable Expression that has value only when the cell value of type is the desired value, so for the example in the question, in the column Value of the summary band in cell with the value "16" you have the expression :

```
$F{type}.equals("A") ? $F{value} : 0
```

and so on for the other types in the summary.